# Submit part of form inside TR data-ID

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to submit only a part of the `form`?

I have a table inside my `form`, but when I submit the `form`, it will submit the complete `form`.

Sometimes this `form` has to much data to submit so I gave every `<tr>` an unique `data-id`, but how can I submit only the inputs inside this `<tr>`?

```
    <form id="urenForm" method="post" action="laborticket.php"> 
        <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover results" id="myTable">
            <tbody>
                <tr data-id="755463">
                    <td><input type="number" id="break_755463" name="break" class="form-control" value="0.75" step=".01" required=""></td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="worked_755463" name="worked" class="form-control" value="8" readonly=""></td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="multiplier_755463" name="multiplier" class="form-control" value="1.000"></td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="update" value="755463">Update</button></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="employee" value="7100">
                    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="113">
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Labor ticket 755463 verwijderen?')" name="verwijderen" value="755463">Verwijderen</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr data-id="755961">
                    <td><input type="number" id="break_755961" name="break" class="form-control" value="0.25" step=".01" required=""></td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="worked_755961" name="worked" class="form-control" value="2.05" readonly=""></td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="multiplier_755961" name="multiplier" class="form-control" value="1.000"></td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="update" value="755961">Update</button></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="employee" value="7100">
                    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="113">
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Labor ticket 755961 verwijderen?')" name="verwijderen" value="755961">Verwijderen</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr data-id="755947">
                    <td><input type="number" id="break_755947" name="break" class="form-control" value="0" step=".01" required=""></td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="worked_755947" name="worked" class="form-control" value="0" readonly=""></td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="multiplier_755947" name="multiplier" class="form-control" value="1.000"></td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" name="update" value="755947">Update</button></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="employee" value="7100">
                    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="113">
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Labor ticket 755947 verwijderen?')" name="verwijderen" value="755947">Verwijderen</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>       
            </tbody>                     
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: use javascript (jQuery) catch the submit, prevent it, then serialize only the fields you want. Afterwards submit them.

Comment: one way is to just put one td, and from there create another form but instead of another table, just simply add a div with borders using css, that way, essentially each row has its own form tag. another way is the solution above form Dieter, you'll need to add js on top